# about SQLite query

Tags: sqlite

I'm using `SQLite` & in that i'm using the following query-

```
INSERT INTO Contact(FirstName, LastName, MobileNumber, IsArchive) VALUES('mina', 'Ambani', '9874587458', 1); SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS 'Identity';
```

this query insert the record & also gives last insert row id of identity column in my table but initially it generates error as-

```
The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the SQL pane:

Unable to parse query text
```

How to remove this error?

thanks.

Comment: What tool are you using to access the SQLite database?

Comment: @user569090 : I'm using SQLite with .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite does not seem to support multiple SQL statements in one query. Run a separate subsequent query. Something like

```
SQLiteCommand IDCmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select last_insert_rowid();", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // EXECUTE INSERT HERE
long id = (long)IDCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Connection open/close and error handling is missing from this example.